# Command line tool to move/modify files/folders in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

Was wondering.
Is there any CLI tool available for Amazon S3 to play around with files/folders, actions like `move`, `delete`, etc.

Basically I got a task where I have to move bunch (a lot) of files from a bucket to a folder on the same bucket, so that I don't have to see whole files when I open the bucket in S3 console.

I am expecting a tool or kind of script which help me move files from one place to a folder on the same bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few days ago, Amazon added new [file commands.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)

The AWS CLI webpage is at http://aws.amazon.com/cli/#file
These are python scripts (Python 2.6 or higher required). On Mac and Linux you can install using 'pip install awscli'. For windows there is an installer.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering if you had heard of Google... No don't take seriously, just kidding. There are several options, e.g.:

- http://s3tools.org/s3cmd
- http://aws.amazon.com/code/1710

HTH

Comment: :-).. I tried but I couldn't get the one, looks like your link to aws.amazon got me the answer.. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

To create a folder and move files into it just use the mv command and include the folder in the path - it will be created automatically.

Example: create folder "newFolder" and move file "pic.jpg" from bucket root:

aws s3 mv s3://bucket-name/pic.jpg s3://bucket-name/newFolder/pic.jpg