# How to delete a folder in s3?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I have the following hierarchy in my s3 bucket

```
bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1
bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1
```

I am able to delete all the files within folder2, but that leaves the bucket with empty folders as folder1/folder2.

What is the appropriate way of deleting those folders?

Here is what I do to delete a particular file:

Where `s3` is my Amazon s3 instance:

```
s3.buckets[my_bucket_name].objects[path].delete
```

Ideally I would like to delete the folders an all the contents.

Comment: Could you achieve this?

Comment: Note that [there are no folders on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html). There are buckets, and files, and that's it. Folders are purely cosmetic based on shared filename prefix.

Answer (score 9):

You can use aws-cli to delete a folder :

> aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/ --recursive

In order to check what the delete operation will delete, you can set 'dryrun' flag :

> aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/ --recursive --dryrun

Comment: This works, but it deletes files one by one. If you have a lot of them, it's going to take a while. If you need a faster version, consider writing a script that calls `DeleteObjects` (can delete up to 1000 files in the same request).

Comment: To be clear: [there _are_ no folders on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html), there is "a bucket" and that bucket can hold "files", and there's nothing in between. The presentation of files using folders is purely cosmetic, so deleting "a folder" literally means telling S3 to "delete every file with the same filename prefix", which it will do one by one.

Answer (score 1):

```
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: '...',
                             access_key_id: '...',
                             secret_access_key: '...')
bucket = 'acme-test'
folder_name = 'my_folder/'

# delete all objects in folder *and folder*

client.list_objects(bucket: bucket, prefix: folder_name).contents.each do |obj|
  client.delete_object(bucket: bucket, key: obj.key)
end
```

- [aws-sdk-s3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/master/gems/aws-sdk-s3) 1.41.0

Answer (score 0):

```
function emptyBucket(bucket, folderName, callback) {
var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Prefix: folderName+ '/'
};
s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    if (data.Contents.length == 0) callback();

    params = { Bucket: bucket };
    params.Delete = { Objects: [] };

    data.Contents.forEach(function (content) {
        params.Delete.Objects.push({ Key: content.Key });
    });

    s3.deleteObjects(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (data.IsTruncated) {
            emptyBucket(bucket, callback);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
});
```

}

Answer (score -1):

http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

http://aws.amazon.com/code/1710

orr
[Command line tool to move/modify files/folders in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579125/command-line-tool-to-move-modify-files-folders-in-amazon-s3)

where a similar question was asked