# Download files from Amazon S3 windows command line utility

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am tasked to automate the process of downloading files from Amazon S3. I am quite new this, after searching on the web I found this command line utility for windows [s3.exe](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=s3)
I run the get command with the below syntax

```
s3 get xxx-xxx/yyyy_yyy/ D:\ /key:****** /secret:*****
```

xxx-xxx(bucketname)
yyyy_yyy(keyprefix)
D:(local path)

When I execute this the only message i see is `s3.exe version 2.0 - check for updates at http://s3.codeplex.com` and then it takes me back to the folder where I run the command. Pardon me if this too basic a question for this forum but if anyone have used this utility some insights will help me achieve this

Comment: When I operating on windows I was using AWS Powershell cmdlet: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Read-S3Object.html

Comment: @congbaoguier thank for the info thats useful, I did more digging and I am going to start using the AWS .net sdk  and the S3 api references. I was not able to download these files using the s3.exe utility due to IAM user rights.Thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: You can use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has an `aws s3 cp` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a file on Amazon S3 from the Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130448/how-to-access-a-file-on-amazon-s3-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Also [Command line tool to move/modify files/folders in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579125/850848).